# MongoDB: Mapping an interface to an implementation

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a mongodb data store and I am trying to save an object that is defined by the interface IProject. When I try to load an object from the datastore, mongo understandably doesn't know which implementation of the interface to use. How do I tell Mongo to always treat an interface as a specific object. i.e. how do I map IProject to Project?

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Project>(p =>
    {               
        p.AutoMap();                    
        p.MapField("_leadTimeTrendData").SetElementName("LeadTimeTrendData");
    });

var client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);
var server = client.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("projectforecasting");
var projects = database.GetCollection<IProject>("Projects");            
return projects.Find(Query.EQ("Name", name)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This gives the following error when I try and load a project.

> The class 'ProjectForecastingCore.Interface.IProject' does not have a field named '_leadTimeTrendData'.

Comment: We're gonna need to see some code here. Not much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`BsonKnownTypesAttribute`](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#specifying-known-types), e.g.

```
[BsonDiscriminator(Required=true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(MyProject))]
interface IProject
{ ... }

class MyProject : IProject
{ ... }
```

This way, MongoDB will automatically store a type discriminator (`{"_t":"MyProject"}`) and the driver knows what `MyProject` is and will create such an object instance.

--- EDIT --- (after the OP's edit)

Is `IProject` really an interface? The error messages indicates it's a class. If `IProject` is always `Project`, isn't it easier to call `database.GetCollection<Project>("Projects")`? That saves you from having to use a discriminator.

Otherwise, to make your code work you need to supply a *discriminator* in `RegisterClassMap`:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Project>(p =>
    {               
        p.AutoMap();                    
        p.SetDiscriminator("type");
        p.MapField("_leadTimeTrendData").SetElementName("LeadTimeTrendData");
    });
```